# jQuery on click again, should hide the box (like toggle)

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have the following example:

https://codepen.io/baidoc/pen/LYVvOZq

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  $(".box").click(function() {
    $(".box").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".boxContent").removeClass("show-content");
    var target = $(this).attr("target");
    $(".boxContent_" + target).addClass("show-content");
  });
});
```

2 Boxes, by default deactivated (hidden), and only once clicked, the content will be shown.

What I'm trying to do: when I click again on the box, it should hide the box (display:none)

I've tried with toggle function, but somehow it doesn't seem to work. What alternative do I have?

Comment: Hi Tudor. It's not clear how the boxes will be clicked if they are initially hidden. Could you clarify that?

Comment: @RomiHalasz they're initially hidden, once clicked, will be shown. However, now that they're open, if I click the same box again, should be hidden again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  $(".box").click(function() {
    var currentActive = $(this).hasClass("active");
    $(".boxContent").removeClass("show-content");
    $(".box").removeClass("active");
    if (!currentActive){
      $(this).addClass("active");
      var target = $(this).attr("target");
      $(".boxContent_" + target).addClass("show-content");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: almost! the problem now is that you can have both boxes open at the same time..

Answer (score 0):

Try this below :

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  $(".box").click(function() {
    $(".box").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
     if($(".boxContent").hasClass("show-content")){  
    $(".boxContent").removeClass("show-content");
     }else{
    var target = $(this).attr("target");
    $(".boxContent_" + target).addClass("show-content");
  };
  });
});
```

Comment: better, however.... if I want to jump directly from Box 1 to 2? It will activate Box 2, and no content visible. PS. please re-check my codepen, I added opacity.